# What might cause sluggish / jerky response to EMPTY window resize in OSX / Cocoa app?

Tags: cocoa, performance, macos, resize, window

**NEW INFO:** Something I just noticed (because this isn't something I'd normally do), but this is a multi-window app, with a tool palette and an image window... the image window is the one with the problem -- the tool window has NO problem with resizing, it is very fast and smooth. So it's just other windows in the app; the image editing window, the image library window.

Something in my app structure may be wrong, but I don't know what. The symptom is that resizing my window doesn't go smoothly -- instead, it hangs for a moment, then "jerks" to the next position. Instruments says that the time is being spent in mach_msg_trap. The window isn't doing anything - I commented out everything in an attempt to narrow down what might be causing it, and now there isn't even a drawrect of mine going on (though the window is of course rendering its title bar and borders, etc.) So this empty window, with zero work to do, is just slow as mud.

I've googled like crazy, I've read tons of docs on runloops and windows and views, and I can't find even a hint of what might cause this.

I'm seeing this problem under 10.5.8, xcode 3.1.3, gcc 4.0 in an 8-core machine with 8 gb of ram, lots free, and plenty of free disk space. I see the same behavior on a dual core macbook pro/2GB and a dual-core macbook/2GB, all running 10.5.8.

When all the code is in place, everything in my app works, but is compromised by the very slow update rate I'm seeing. cpu utilization isn't very high, so there's a lot more time available for display, it just isn't being used.

With all my display code commented out (literally... top to bottom, no drawrect, no view code, so the app literally is doing *nothing*) the jerkyness is the same, but cpu utilization is almost zero. It's like it isn't calling the windows drawrect often enough. But I can't find any reason why it would fail to do so.

...and by "jerky", I mean that as I drag the little resize widget at the bottom right of the window at a moderate or even slow speed, the frame stays where it is, then "snaps" a huge distance to catch up with where the mouse has gotten to, then repeats.

Add the code back in, and it acts the same. So it's not the drawing code. My instinct says is a structural problem -- something done wrong in IB, or in how I set up the views, etc. But I can't find anything I'm supposed to do as a matter of "this has to be done to make resize/redraw response or runloop response snappy" in any of the docs or online hints.

There's a custom view, dragged from IB's palette of such things, in the window. It's set to resize automatically with the window size. And it does. But it follows the window perfectly, which is to say, jerkily. drawrect or no drawrect.

Any real cocoa experts have any ideas?

Comment: Desperate times call for drastic measures. If Instruments and profiling don’t help you, I’d recommend starting another project and incrementally adding bits of your current project until you hit this problem.

Comment: Thank you for that. I guess that's what I'll have to do at some point. Interestingly, I've noticed similar behavior in other apps: Adium, for instance, starts out with snappy window drawing/resizing, but after a while, the windows resize like my project does -- in VERY slow fits and jerks. My app has something else in common with Adium, too, it has multiple windows: a very long tool palette window and an image window. The image window is the one with the resizing issues, content or no. Interesting!

Comment: Have you considered talking to the Adium developers on Freenode? They might have some insight as to why this happens.

Comment: I've posted over there... no responses today. We'll see. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding an automatically generated drawing proxy to ensure the image to be drawn is never larger than the screen it is on, I've eliminated visible evidence of the problem.

**1)** The machine is fast enough to draw the screen-sized proxy quickly,

**2)** the end-of-resize refresh of the tool window is successful because of that, and

**3)** resizing (and drawing) is smooth because I've short-circuited the drawrect of the toolwidow when the image window is resizing.

I'm going to move on and call this dealt with by this series of workarounds, though I still think there's clearly an underlying OS or structure issue somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Your app may be blocked communicating with the WindowServer (I see that happen when I run Minecraft or Starcraft 2, for example). Take samples in "All Thread States" mode in Shark or Instruments, and look for CGSSynchronizeBackingStore, if my fuzzy memory is getting the name right. Something like that anyway.

The "All Thread States" mode is so that blocked time is reported as well as running time.

Comment: well, ok, lets say that this is what's happening... why would that happen, and what can I do about it? Remember, it's happening with an empty window, in an otherwise not busy machine, and on all manner of hardware -- minis, mac pros, macbook pros, macbooks, airs -- under leopard and snow leopard.

Comment: Ah hm. I missed the "happens on multiple machines" part. Does it happen in other apps on multiple machines? I haven't seen a thing like that in Adium that I recall (I used to work on it).

Comment: BTW, I looked, and I'm not seeing that or anything like it... most time is in mach_msg_trap. GOod tip though, I'll remember.

Comment: Now, that, I don't know. I am not seeing it on multiple windows with firefox, for instance, or on any single windows. But I've got three adium windows open, one is the contact list, the other two are chats I constantly keep open (the ladyfriend and another dev) and those things sometimes take 5...10 seconds to respond to a corner drag. This particular machine is a six-monitor machine, so there are some extra complications I suppose, but as I mentioned, none of the single window apps is showing any sluggishness at all, they just rip right along when resized. I want that behavior BAD. :)

Comment: going to open multiple windows on adium on my macbook pro tomorrow, instead of the big machine here, and see how it acts after running for a while there. Will report back.

Comment: Post a link to the sample? mach_msg_trap just means "blocked"; All Thread States profiles are also fairly tricky to read correctly...

Comment: couple things - don't now how to get the sample to you - instruments provides a list in a window... what do I need to do to get that? Is there some way to save it? Or do you want a screenshot? Also, just as an FYI, I'm running aduim on my macbook pro, two windows (three with list) the same as my big machine, and on first open, the windows are fast. I'll see if they slow down during the day.

Comment: ran adium all day on the macbook pro; same config, same connections as usual. No slowdowns. Will try again tomorrow. I've got it open again on my desk and its still fast there, too... I'll see if it slows down tomorrow.

Comment: Catfish_Man, I've saved a trace made while trying to resize the window. You'll find it here: (http://www.ourtimelines.com/JerkyWindow.trace.zip)

Comment: What to *do* about it though... hrm. Not sure on that. Maybe a file a bug at bugreport.apple.com if you have steps to reproduce it. Or post on the developer forums. You need a CG expert here.

Comment: Aha, this might be relevant... http://lists.apple.com/archives/quartz-dev/2009/Oct/msg00051.html

Comment: Also check your window backing store type. It should be buffered.

Comment: ...and remember... it does this with no drawrect function. it's not my drawing that's tying it up.

Comment: NEWS: I have found something that affects the bug -- basically, I can turn it on or off. If I hide my tool window, the image window immediately begins to behave - smooth as grease. Now here's the fun part. When I restore the tool window, the image window CONTINUES to behave. Finally, if I touch the title bar of the tool window, the image window goes back to its draggy, jerky self. This is repeatable; minimize the tool window, everything works. restore it, still works. Touch it, the lagging returns. more...

Comment: NEWS, continued: I've looked through the window and view code for anything where I might have tied one window or view that's in one of them, to the other, but didn't find anything like that. I"m back to the idea that it's a structural problem. Refactoring/building the app isn't really an option -- this thing is huuuuge. So I'm still hunting, but the scope just got a lot narrower. I may subclass sendEvent for the tool window and see what is happening over there when I resize the image window. I wouldn't think anything was going on, but suspect something is...

Comment: argh... thought I was being all clever there... nothing interesting in terms of messages at all. hmmm. More experimenting...

Comment: ok, -- the drawrects on the tool window -- which is actually on another screen in my setup -- are being called when the slowdown occurs. Shrink the tool window, the drawrect isn't called, the main window draws great. The thing is, there's no reason to call drawrect on the tool window here. I can probably short-circuit the behavior by setting a flag that prevents the tool panel drawrect from running when the image window is being resize, but... sheeesh. Ok, back to it.

Comment: If I (temporarily, I realize this isn't a fix) put awareness into the toolwindow drawrects of the liveResize state of the image window, the app works except that the tool window gets hosed when the image window resizes etc. But with the tool window in the other screen, I see NO reason why it would be asked to redraw. I'm certainly not doing it. Remember that I can take ALL my drawing code out, and this still happens. The delay is in drawing the (huge) toolwindow, which it shouldn't be doing. Any ideas anyone? I'm fresh out, and I'm also exhausted.... 5am here. Will check back on the morrow.

Comment: I unfortunately have to work today since I broke stuff pretty badly, so I won't get to this for a while. Strong debugging so far though, sounds like you're on the right track!

Comment: lol ... I know how that goes. Thanks for the kind words. Still hunting. Had some other weird behavior too... click in an empty view (it just draws a back backdrop), and no longer -- ever -- get a keyDown method call. Anywhere in any view in that window unless it was closed and re-opened. So I subclassed sendEvent, caught the keyDown there, and sent it straight on the right view (always the same one in this design) and viola, all fixed. But I shouldn't have had to do that. :/

Comment: Darn it, no luck. Worked on it all day, trying to figure out why Cocoa is telling the wrong window to refresh. Nary a clue. No hints on the net, at least either that or my Google-fu is zenless. Pulled a trick with a watchdog timer in an aux thread to refresh the tools after the main image is done resizing, and that works up to moderate size images on my 8-core machine, but when Cocoa slows down on a big one (like, 21mp), I still get toolWindow fail-to-refresh artifacts, so that's a non-starter. Less capable machines will have trouble with even smaller images. But I dunno what else to do.